# WinAPI How to Apply Edit field text change?

Tags: winapi, sendmessage

I'm working with 3d party application. Changing a text in Edit control using

```
SendMessageW(m_edit_handle,WM_SETTEXT,0,str_address);
```

And it works fine.. It changes visually in the window. But once I click a button (also programmatically) it works as there is a default value but not the one I set with SendMessageW.
Just wondering if after changing the text in Edit window I have to call some other method to force Windows to update the actual value in the field?

Comment: To automate a UI use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how the target app is coded, you *may* need to issue an [`EN_CHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/en-change) notification to the Edit's parent window. Sending `WM_SETTEXT` will not send that notification, as it is meant to be sent when the *user* makes changes to the Edit's content, not when *code* does.

```cpp
SendMessageW(m_edit_handle, WM_SETTEXT, 0, str_address);
SendMessageW(GetParent(m_edit_handle), WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(GetDlgCtrlID(m_edit_handle), EN_CHANGE), LPARAM(m_edit_handle));
```

Comment: If I send NotifyWinEvent() it's supposed to be the same, right?

Comment: No. [`NotifyWinEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-notifywinevent) is part of the UI Automation infrastructure, not the window manager (which this answer uses). If you were using UI Automation to begin with ([`IAccessible::put_accValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleacc/nf-oleacc-iaccessible-put_accvalue)) the system would do all the change notification propagation for you, so you wouldn't be in a position where you feel the need to help the system out.